# Integrate Bootstrap Carousel in Wordpress and paginate to show 3 post per page

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, carousel

Im trying to integrate this http://jsfiddle.net/Va8Un/10/ on the author page for showing all the post from a custom post type.

Here is my testing code that shows what i want to do, this code shows the same post on the 3 span4:

```
<?php 
$args1 = array(
'post_type' => array( 'peliculas' ),
'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query1 = new WP_Query( $args1 );
if ( $query1->have_posts() ) { ?>
<div class="carousel slide" id="autor-pelicules">
 <div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php 
    $i = 0;
    while ( $query1->have_posts( )) : $i++; $query1->the_post();
    $active = ($i == 1) ? ' active' : '';
    ?>  
<div class="item <?php echo $active; ?>">

    <div class="span4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <?php   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {   
                    the_post_thumbnail('mini', array ('class' => 'widget-uef'));
                } else { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/tema/imatges/predefinides/no-poster-65x90.png" class="widget-uef" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" />
                <?php } ?>
                </a> 
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="span4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <?php   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {   
                    the_post_thumbnail('mini', array ('class' => 'widget-uef'));
                } else { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/tema/imatges/predefinides/no-poster-65x90.png" class="widget-uef" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" />
                <?php } ?>
                </a> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="span4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <?php   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {   
                    the_post_thumbnail('mini', array ('class' => 'widget-uef'));
                } else { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/tema/imatges/predefinides/no-poster-65x90.png" class="widget-uef" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" />
                <?php } ?>
                </a> 
    </div>
  </div>

</div> 
    <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>
</div>
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#autor-pelicules" data-slide="prev"><img src="<?php echo $jp_imatges . 'carousel-l.png'; ?>" alt="Pel&iacute;cula anterior" /></a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#autor-pelicules" data-slide="next"><img src="<?php echo $jp_imatges . 'carousel-r.png'; ?>" alt="Pel&iacute;cula siguiente" /></a>
```

I tried to do with one query in several ways but im not able to show 3 diferent posts without using **'posts_per_page' => 3** in the **$args1**, when i use **'posts_per_page' => 3** the retrieved posts are ok but the query has no pagination because only retrieve this 3 posts.

Any idea on how to implement this with a wordpress query?

Comment: How many post do you have so far? Make sure you have at least 3 to show pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 2 things from your code

1. You need to add this **'paged' => $paged** to your **$args1**
2. You need to call WordPress pagination function which can be done using this `<?php page_navi(); // use the page navi function ?>`

I think if you use these it should work for you. Let me know if it was helpful or any results you get after using this :)